# Anotações de controllers e services

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

No Spring 3 existem as anotações de classe `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Controller` e `@Repository`.

Eu sei que o `@Component` é o único que pode ser usado em todos os casos (*Controller*, *Service* e *Repository*).

Mas qual é a vantagem e desvantagem de usar essa anotação que é mais genérica?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ao contrário da anotação genérica `@Component`, as anotações específicas marcam as classes com estereótipos, assim como na UML.

Dessa forma, se uma classe é anotada com `@Service` você pode pressupor que ela contém regras de negócio, se a anotação é `@Repository` é óbvio que a classe implementa o pattern [Respository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) (não é igual ao DAO, mas chega a ser parecido) e se a anotação é `@Controller` você também pode associar diretamente a um controlador do modelo MVC.

Embora a princípio pareça apenas um enfeite, é possível listar algumas vantagens:

- Ajuda na separação de camadas da aplicação.
- Facilita a utilização de POA (AOP - Aspect Oriented Programming), como no caso do módulo Spring Data JPA, que "gera" dinamicamente a implementação de interfaces anotadas com Repository.
- Permite o tratamento específico de exceções lançadas por camadas específicas, onde temos novamente o exemplo da camada de acesso a dados (`Repository`), onde o Spring irá traduzir exceções específicas de um banco de dados em classes padronizadas.
- Você pode criar qualquer funcionalidade que necessite de tratamento geral por camada, basta usar um pouco a imaginação. :)

Sinceramente, não encontrei desvantagens no uso das anotações específicas com relação à anotação genérica. A única ressalva é quanto ao desempenho do `component-scan`, que encontra as anotações automaticamente (independente de qual você está usando), pois ele pode atrasar a inicialização da aplicação. Mapear os beans em XML melhora o tempo de inicialização se isso for algo crítico.