# O que faz a anotação @Component?

Tags: java, spring

O que de fato o Spring faz quando colocamos a anotação `@Component` em uma classe? Como funciona "por baixo dos panos"

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/139/227

Comment: Artigo relacionado :)
http://luizricardo.org/2014/03/quais-anotacoes-usar-nos-componentes-do-spring-3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acordo com a própria [definição dos criadores](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html), ela representa um componente (`bean`) que é detectado automaticamente quando trabalhamos com configurações baseadas em annotations e busca de caminhos de classes.

Outros elementos, como `@Repository`, `@Service` e `@Controller`, são alguns estereótipos que implementam a `@Component`. Dessa forma, você pode criar uma outra especialização de `@Component` de acordo com a sua necessidade.

Exemplo:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public @interface MinhaClasse{
...
}
```

Dessa forma, temos uma nova especialização de `@Component`.

Answer (score 8):

O Spring suporta a anotação `@Component` desde de sua versão [2.5](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html), e a mesma serve para indicar ao framework que aquela classe é um *bean* que deverá ser administrado pela implementação de [IoC Container](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) do Spring.

Como o Weslley Tavares comentou, a anotação `@Component` é um estereótipo, e as especializações dele são `@Repository`, `@Service` e `@Controller`.

Quando uma classe é anotada com `@Component` significa que a mesma usará o padrão de injeção de depêndencia, e será elegível para auto-configuração e auto-detecção de *beans* anotados à partir de escaneamento de *classpath* que o IoC Container do Spring faz.

Ao carregar a aplicação, o Spring escanea o *classpath* atrás de classes anotadas com `@Component` ou especializações para então criar uma instância com escopo do tipo **singleton** por padrão, ou seja, os *beans* são **stateless** (não devem guardar estado), assim não sendo necessário uma nova instância do bean a cada vez que houver uma referência.

O Spring só escaneará os *beans* elegíveis que você especificar no arquivo `applicationContext.xml`, dessa forma:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.path.dos.beans" />
```

### Uso prático

A anotação `@Component` deve ser usada em nível de classe, dessa forma:

```
@Component
public class Foo {
//implementação da  classe
}
```

Para referenciar a mesma em outro contexto (obter a instância), pode se usar a anotação `@Autowired`, dessa forma:

```
@Component
public class Bar {
   @Autowired
   private Foo foo;
}
```

Comment: Ou, se for utilizar um bean fora de um `@Component`, deverá utilizar a anotação `@SpringBean`, não `@Autowired`.

Comment: Gustavo Cinque, a anotação `@SpringBean` faz parte do framework Apache Wicket, que da suporte para injeção de beans do spring, sendo necessário importar a dependência do mesmo.
Uma outra forma de utilizar o bean sem `@Autowired` seria fazendo a injeção manual da classe que irá utilizar esse bean no contexto de injeção de depêndencia do spring direto no código, colocando essa linha no construtor da classe: `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);`

Comment: For real? Eu sempre uso Wicket, deve ser por isso que confundi :/